# Making Honeycomb ActionBar compatible with ICS

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've an existing app which has couple of tabs, buttons in the actionbar. I want to port it to ICS, My concern is how will the items stack up on the ICS device?

Will all of the `showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` be hidden into menu? or will it make a new actionbar at the bottom like ICS gmail app does it.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions will stack up at the top, and be hidden if there is not enough space.
If you Split the Action Bar then they will come at the botton
You have to configure the Application tag to configure it to be split

```
  <application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:logo="@drawable/logo"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="true" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
```